# Sending a Packet to a Number of Threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-17

I have a central information source (architecturally) and need some way to send the packet to each thread which does a fast operation and then waits for a new packet afterwards.

I'm weighing the pros and cons of a distributed system, as opposed to a hierarchical system.

I could give each thread its own BlockingQueue, but then I would have to:

> a) make a blocking queue each class, and then make sure that it is
> populated from the central packet source (which I could automate with
> a method to do such a thing).

Or the central queue method would be something like:

A child class of blocking queue whose take method:

> ```
> var result = topOfQueue
> //wait on countdown latch static variable for ~7 threads
> //latch released, immediatly wait on cyclic barrier for 8 threads (7 + 1 thread which is removes the topmost queue element then joins the barrier
> ```
>
> the cyclic barrier).
> return result;

Is this a good architecture given my objectives of sharing the packet with each thread? Or is there a far more efficient architecture that I'm missing (or a class that already exists for this?)

Which would scale better?

Comment: "need some way to send the packet to each thread" This is the listener pattern

Comment: Also, this is probably premature optimization.  Choose an approach and benchmark it.  If it doesn't scale the way you want, try a different one.  Nobody here will be able to tell you, since only you know the workload characteristics.

Comment: @ControlAltDel This is an excellent point! Didn't think to use observers as I haven't written them much in the past!

Comment: The java.util.Observable/Observer is deprecated since Java 9 and will not give you multi threading.

Comment: The `Observer` design pattern fam :) @pveentjer

Answer (score 0):

I would start with something simple like an Executor. It manages a bunch of threads that receive work through a shared queue.

Also, I would set a set of (micro) benchmarks to confirm your design choices.

[edit] Or do you need to packet to be processed by every thread? In that case, you could make a set of single-threaded executors and copy the packet to each executor.

These are just some suggestions on how to go about it. I have no clue of this is a proper solution in your design.